# merging two .txt files together with data columns side by side

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to merge two text files together with the data stored in separate columns in an output file `merged_file.txt`.

File_1:

```
 Temp[K] Time(s) dT
 314.1 1.2 0.4
 317.4 4.2 0.3
 319.9 7.2 0.5
```

File_2:

```
 Temp[K] Time(s) dT
 312.1 1.2 0.2
 315.3 4.2 0.3
 316.7 7.2 0.2
```

Merged_file:

```
Temp[K] Time(s) dT Temp[K] Time(s) dT
314.1 1.2 0.4 312.1 1.2 0.2
```

I'm relatively new to Unix and the bash shell, but I've done some research and found `paste` and `pr`. For `paste` I tried to use the delimiter `' '` but it does not work.

```bash
$ paste -d' ' File_1.txt File_2.txt | column -s $'\t' -t > merged_file.txt 
$ pr -m -t File_1.txt File_2.txt  > merged_file.txt
```

The data is always stored beneath each other and it wouldn't work under any circumstances.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll do it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and the built-in variable `FILENAME` to read each of the files into an array and then output them side-by-side using the `END` block. You can use a simple check `if ($0 == "")` to check for and discard empty lines.

For example where your data is in files `f1` and `f2`you can do:

```
awk '
    FILENAME=="f1"{if ($0 != "") a[i++] = $0} 
    FILENAME=="f2"{if ($0 != "") b[j++] = $0} 
    END {for (k = 0; k < i; k++) print a[k], b[k]}' f1 f2
```

**Explanation**

- `FILENAME=="f1"{if ($0 != "") a[i++] = $0}` if the file is `f1`, and the line isn't empty, read it into array `a[]`;
- ditto for file `f2` but read into the `b[]` array;
- `END {for (k = 0; k < i; k++) print a[k], b[k]}` after all lines in both files are processed, loop `i` times printing the contents of the `a[]` and `b[]` arrays separated by a space, (you can add an additional check to ensure `i == j`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk '
>     FILENAME=="f1"{if ($0 != "") a[i++] = $0}
>     FILENAME=="f2"{if ($0 != "") b[j++] = $0}
>     END {for (k = 0; k < i; k++) print a[k], b[k]}' f1 f2
Temp[K] Time(s) dT Temp[K] Time(s) dT
314.1 1.2 0.4 312.1 1.2 0.2
317.4 4.2 0.3 315.3 4.2 0.3
319.9 7.2 0.5 316.7 7.2 0.2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked pretty good and is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

You use `column -s $'\t'`.
The -s option of column specifies the delimiter used in the input file.
When you have spaces in your input files and use `paste -d' '` leave it as default.

```
$ paste -d' ' File_1 File_2 | column -t
```

```
Temp[K]  Time(s)  dT   Temp[K]  Time(s)  dT
314.1    1.2      0.4  312.1    1.2      0.2
317.4    4.2      0.3  315.3    4.2      0.3
319.9    7.2      0.5  316.7    7.2      0.2
```